# What causes a format exception when using decimal points in styles?

Tags: wpf, react-native

I am seeing crashes in my React Native application on some users machines. It appears that using a style like this causes a FormatExcpetion:

`StyleSheet.create({login: { margin: "7.8%"}});`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this comes from float.Parse() when the locale of the machine/AppDomain uses commas for floating point instead of periods. You need to add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to the float.Parse to override.

The fix in react-native-windows has been merged (but not published) here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/pull/1855